# High CPU core usage from System Interrupts

Tags: windows-7, performance, cpu, cpu-usage, high-cpu-usage

The CPU usage on my [AMD Phenom II X4 820](http://products.amd.com/pages/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=634&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) hasn't gone below 25% in days, and I realized that it’s because my 4th core is constantly at 100% load.

I have spent quite a while trying to figure out why, and the only suggestion I could find that I hadn’t tried already is to turn off sound effects, and this caused my CPU usage to go right down and then spike back up. Now it just spikes up and down, and it’s still System Interrupts that’s causing it.

What could be happening here, and is there anything I could do to stop it? This wasn’t happening before the last time I did a full wipe.

[image: CPU usage]

Comment: capture a xperf trace to analyze it: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Comment: Will do as soon as I have time. Can I use LatencyMon?

Comment: LatencyMon looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/DB5T5Mn.png). Also, my 4th core isn't spiking up and down like it was before, it's just staying at the top.

@JakeGould That was because of ndis.sys, which doesn't seem to be the problem here. I was using Teamviewer for this as I'm not at home right now.

Comment: storport.sys = HDD activity. Do you use the Microsoft or AM AHCI driver?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I use the Microsoft one.

Comment: ^^ @magicandre1981 I take that back, I was actually using the AMD one. I rolled back to the Microsoft driver and rebooted and that fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I was actually using the AMD ACPI driver, and it seems like they are buggy, because I rolled back to the Microsoft one and rebooted, and that fixed it.

Comment: nice to hear this :)